# Как решить задачу Разделение Нлогони?

Tags: c#, c++

Постановка задачи:

> После нескольких лет горячих споров о территории, жители страны
> Нлогонии решили разделить страну на 4 части. Все согласились, что
> будет определена Точка Раздела, от которой на карте будут проведены
> две линии - одна с севера на юг, другая с востока на запад. Начиная с
> самой западной и самой северной, по часовой стрелке, страны будут
> называться Северозападна Нлогония, Северовосточная Нлогония,
> Юговосточная нлогония и Югозападная Нлогония. [image: введите сюда описание изображения] ООН решило, что будет существовать страница в
> интернете, где жители смогут определить, в какой стране теперь
> находятся их дома. Вас наняли реализовать этот проект. Ввод: Входные
> данные представляют собой массив из 4 чисел: первые два - координаты
> Точки Раздела(x, y), следующие два - координаты дома(тоже х, у).
>
> Вы должны вывести результат:
>
> - border если дом находится на границе
> - NW если дом находится в северо-западной части страны
> - NE если дом находится в северо-восточной части страны
> - SW если дом находится в юго-западной части страны
> - SE если дом находится в юго--восточной части страны

Нашел решения но хотелось бы самому решить и не понимаю даже с чего начать. Может кто подсказать с чего начать

Comment: Начать? со ввода данных :) Потом сравнивать координаты x и y, чтоб выяснить, не на границе ли точка. Ну, а потом решать, в каком она квадранте...

Comment: А заданные х и у значения у нас длина осей ?

Comment: Никакой длины осей нет. В задаче же описано - первая пара - точка разделения

Answer (score 1):

```
int x0, y0, x, y;
cin >> x0 >> y0 >> x >> y;
if (x0 == x || y0 == y) 
{ 
    cout << "border";
}
else
{
    cout << (y < y0 ? 'S' : 'N');
    cout << (x < x0 ? 'W' : 'E');
}
```